# Why AWS Account tab is missing in my dashboard?? can't access AWS console

Tags: amazon-web-services

I got approved mail from AWS. when after I log into the AWS account there's no AWS Account tab showing. Am I missing something??

[image]

Comment: This is not AWS, but AWS Educate account. Are you part of any class there?

Comment: Refer this https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/create-and-activate-aws-account/

Comment: For support on AWS Educate, use the "Contact Us" link at the bottom of that page.